# Create a Button with "id" property in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I want to create a button in my xaml file with 'id' property. But it says "property id was not found in button".

I have set the build options to "android resource".

Here is my xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<android:RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="Records.Droid.Video">

<Button id=""/>
```

Edited to add: I am working on Xamarin Forms

Comment: Hello @user. Perhaps you should give a little bit more context. The code you're using could be helpful as well. Is this Xamarin Forms or just regular Xamarin. I'd take it's android since you say you've set the build options to "android resource".

Comment: I am working on Xamarin forms.

Comment: @user this is not Xamarin Forms, so my answer was a correct answer to the wrong question...

Comment: At the end I had to ask this question to be closed - this is some mix of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Forms that you call 'Xamarin.Forms' but has more elements of Xamarin.Android. It has so many errors that there is nothing to answer, you have to learn many things before being able to ask a proper question.

Comment: Yeah, its a wrong question. Thanks for pointing it out